# SoapFault - faultcode: 'SOAP-ENV:Server' faultstring: 'Procedure 'salesOrderList' not present' faultactor: 'null' detail: null

Tags: magento-1.9, soap, soap-api-v2

I am getting the session id and i am trying to fetch salesOrderList in my android application .I am using Ksoap2 android library to query my magento host But unfortunately i am getting this following error .

and this is link of github where i have exported .Please help me 
https://github.com/sudhirbelagali/InchooSoap

```
SoapFault - faultcode: 'SOAP-ENV:Server' faultstring: 'Procedure 'salesOrderList' not present' faultactor: 'null' detail: null
```

Please help me

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about SOAP calls on android

Comment: The magento order list API is default Magento, I think there might be something wrong with the call in Android

Comment: @sander Mangel ..This question is about the configuration of Magento at the admin panel as well.  and I am unable to fetch the product list using SOAP V2. That is the only reason I posted .